# Why is the base type not returned when no generic type specified?

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I have a code like this:

```
public class A<T extends String> {

    T field;
    List<T> fields;

    public T getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public List<T> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public static void test(){
        A a = new A();
        String s = a.getField();
        List<String> ss = a.getFields();
    }
}
```

Why when creating `A` with no generic type `getFiled` returns `String` but `getFileds` returns `List<Object>`?

I have to define `A` as `A<String> a = new A<>()` for this to work properly.

Thanks,

Comment: By not specifying any generic type, you are declaring that your type use site doesn't use _any_ generics information. This means that in `test()` method effective signature of `getFields()` is `List getFields()` (without generics), not `List<String> getFields()` as you thought.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov So why `field` is returned as `String`?

Comment: Because there is no generics in signature of `T getField()`. Once that type is compiled, there would be a `String getField()` and a bridge method generated by the compiler to support using `getField()` with arbitrary types. None of those use generics.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: `getField` will return an Object, why do you keep saying it returns a String? My mistake I see now.

Comment: @matt, `<T>` is bound, so actual compiled `getFields()` returns `String`, not `Object`.

Comment: You don't know what T is but you know it is an Object that extends String. So getField can return an Object that can be cast to String. You should be able to declare `List<? extends String> ss = a.getFields();`

Comment: @matt it still shows the same warning as in OP's example. So no, it doesn't fix.

Comment: @Michel_T. (sorry, pressed enter from wrong window.) I didn't realize the ops issue was the warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The erasure of the type param `T` in the declaration `T field` is `String`, because `T` has bound:

```
<T extends String>
```

and any `subtype` of a `String` is also a `String`<sup>1</sup>.

But, this doesn't apply to generic `List<T>`. It stems from the fact that generics are not covariant:

```
List<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Object> obj = str; // Error: incompatible types (even though String extends Object)
```

The erasure of `List<T>` in the declaration `List<T> fields` is `List`, particularly because `List<T>` can hold a `String` or its `subtypes`<sup>1</sup>. And given that `A` is a raw type, compiler can't guess the type of the elements in the list returned by the `getFields()` method.

Anyway, this line of code:

```
List<T> fields;
```

is compiled ([Erasure of Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)) into:

```
List fields;
```

As a result, when you write:

```
A a = new A();  instead of  A<String> a = new A<>();
```

you lose the type safety and get an "Unchecked assignment" warning - in this case, compiler can not guarantee that the `fields list` is exactly the `List<String>`:

```
List<String> list = a.getFields(); // Unchecked assignment: 'List' to 'List<String>' ...
```

**P.S.** Don't use raw types!

---

<sup>1 - As you know, `String` class is final and can't be extended. Replace it with any type that can be extended if you wish.</sup>

Comment: +1 … in other words, given the constraint, whatever `getField` returns is assignable to `String`, while whatever `getFields` returns is *not* necessarily assignable to `List<String>` (if we ignore that `String` is `final`).

Comment: @Konrad Thank you for comment! That is actually what I wanted to show in my answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph yes, but it’s worth noting that a `List<? extends X>` still guarantees that all contained objects are assignable to `X`, but you are not allowed to insert new objects of type `X`, as they may be incompatible to the list’s actual type. If you can preclude insertions, you can make the assignment, i.e. if you have an `A<?> a;`, you can use `List<String> list = Collections.unmodifiableList( a.getFields());`, as the wrapper prevents you from inserting incompatible elements.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the raw type, you still have your bounds. So `T extends String` you know that whatever is returned will extend String. When you use the raw type it is *like* having `? extends String`.

```
A<?> a = new A<>();
String s = a.getField(); 
List<? extends String> ss = a.getFields();
String s2 = ss.get(0);
```

Of course there will be an error NPE, but the idea is there.

One difference for the raw types, all of the type information in get Fields is lost because a raw-typed list is returned.

```
List ss = a.getFields();
```

This means, even the bound of String is lost.

Also, String is a final class, so the constraints here don't really add any value, because we know that `T` is always a String. You can just as well use:

```
class A {
    String field;
    List<String> fields;

    public String getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public List<String> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }

    public static void test(){
        A a = new A();
        String s = a.getField();
        List<String> ss = a.getFields();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but only here I can put the code. So I tried this example (but I've named it `TestGenerics` and add `main` instead of `test()`) and then I decompiled it:

```
javap -c TestGenerics
Compiled from "TestGenerics.java"
public class TestGenerics<T extends java.lang.String> {
  T field;

  java.util.List<T> fields;

  public TestGenerics();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public T getField();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #2                  // Field field:Ljava/lang/String;
       4: areturn

  public java.util.List<T> getFields();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #3                  // Field fields:Ljava/util/List;
       4: areturn

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #4                  // class TestGenerics
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #5                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: astore_1
       8: aload_1
       9: invokevirtual #6                  // Method getField:()Ljava/lang/String;
      12: astore_2
      13: aload_1
      14: invokevirtual #7                  // Method getFields:()Ljava/util/List;
      17: astore_3
      18: return
}
```

As we can see in code `field` and `getField` still have the generic `T` type, rather than `compiled into String`. So why does `getField()` work fine?

Comment: You're within bounds, eg. If I have a `class B extends Runnable` then I can use `Runnable b = new B();`  In this case you have `T extends String` so you can assign a T to String. getFields returns a raw type so just List and the information that T extends String is lost.